# Bash 4.4 local readonly array variable scoping: bug?

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-array

The following script fails when run with bash 4.4.20(1)

```bash
#!/bin/bash
bar() {
  local args=("y")
}

foo() {
  local -r args=("x")
  bar
}

foo
```

with error `line 3: args: readonly variable` but succeeds when run with bash 4.2.46(2), which makes sense after reading [24.2. Local Variables](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/localvar.html).

The following script with non-array variables runs without any issues:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
bar() {
  local args="y"
}

foo() {
  local -r args="x"
  bar
}

foo
```

I could not find any [changes](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES) that explain the difference between bash 4.2.46(2) and bash 4.4.20(1).

Q: is this a bug in bash 4.4.20(1)? if this is expected behavior then why does the second script not fail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your script runs correctly with release 5.1 of the `bash` shell, but not with intermediate releases after 4.3.

The bug or bugs might have been introduced around release 4.3 or 4.4.  Multiple changes touched on how read-only declarations and variables work in the development leading up to both releases.

There are at least two entries in the change log that may relate to fixing the involved bugs:

1. For `bash-5.0-alpha`, the change log [has this to say](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES#n1725) (I'm assuming that referencing the `readonly` builtin also means `local -r` was affected):

> Fixed a bug that could cause builtins like `readonly` to behave differently when applied to arrays and scalar variables within functions.

2. For `bash-5.1-alpha`, an additional bug that could be related to this [is also mentioned](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES#n893):

> Fixed a bug that caused local variables with the same name as variables appearing in a function's temporary environment to not be marked as local.

---

Bisecting using [the shell's Git repository](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git) and your script, we arrive at the bug being introduced with [`bash-4.4-rc1`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/commit/?h=bash-4.4-rc1), and then later fixed in [`bash-5.1-alpha`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/commit/?h=bash-5.1-alpha). Since both are big commits, it's difficult to point to any particular changes in the code.

Comment: The bug (if it's really a bug, but I think it is) is present in bash 5.0.17 on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @Kusalananda thank you very much for your extensive reply, I agree with your analysis. As a workaround I will remove all '-r' references from our codebase.